Display related Products on an actors profile page based on taxonomy - Woocommerce
I was wondering if someone can help me.
I have profile pages of actors and I want to display woocommerce Products they're featured in from their attached "Actors" taxonomy.
I currently use PODS and the following shortcode
[products limit="8" columns="4" attribute="pa_actors" visibility="visible" paginate="true" terms="{@post_title}"]
To display it using their post title which is the same as the taxonomy value. But this leaves me unable to customize the display. I'm wondering if someone can help me display it better?
I've tried looking at various PHP code I've seen on here but I'm at a complete loss as to the terms I need or even how I display it after I inserted the code.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Direclty shortcode like [products limit="8" columns="4" attribute="pa_actors" visibility="visible" paginate="true" terms="{@post_title}"] this will not work
Like below you can try
function display_products_by_actor($taxonomy, $term, $limit = 8, $columns = 4) {
    // Define the query arguments
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => $limit,
        'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $term,
            ),
        ),
    );

    // Create a new query
    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        echo '<div class="products-by-actor">';
        echo '<div class="products-grid" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">';

        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            global $product;

            // Display product details
            echo '<div class="product-item" style="flex: 1 0 ' . (100 / $columns) . '%; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 10px;">';
            echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($product->get_id(), 'medium') . '</a>';
            echo '<h3><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h3>';
            echo '<p>' . $product->get_price_html() . '</p>';
            echo '</div>';
        }

        echo '</div>'; // Close products-grid
        echo '</div>'; // Close products-by-actor

        // Restore original Post Data
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        echo '<p>No products found for this actor.</p>';
    }
}


use below code in your profile page template

$actor_term = get_the_title(); // Use the actor's name as the term slug

// Call the function to display products
display_products_by_actor('pa_actors', $actor_term, 8, 4);

